# double loan representation feasibility in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

is it possible to do somthing like this in d3js, and how ?

[image]

If not, is there another js lib to do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Yes: just paint the blue rectangle before the orange one.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I would appreciate if you can provide me a sample. I just started using this lib.

Comment: Sorry, but no: I'll not write code from scratch. If you provide **your** code (even not working), with your data, I can help you.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i started working based on a sample on the net. https://jsfiddle.net/h89bbp2b/  "datas" representing my loans, do you know why do i see nothing ?

Comment: You did a good job. Compare that fiddle with my code to see what didn't work. Just a tip: don't use loops like that `forEach` for painting the elements in a D3 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating the dataviz you want, you have to use a linear scale for both axes:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
```

For the domains, I'm adding 50% (that is, multiplying for 1.5), for a nicer visual:

```
x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.duration;
}) * 1.5]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.monthly;
}) * 1.5]);
```

Then, use this to append the rectangles:

```
var bars = g.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return x(d.duration);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.monthly);
    })
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.monthly);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return colours(d.duration);
    });
```

Remember: for this to work, the data for the smaller rectangle has to come **after** the data for the larger one.

Here is the working demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var colours = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
  monthly: 1258.5,
  duration: 212
}, {
  monthly: 1058.5,
  duration: 120
}];

x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.duration;
}) * 1.5]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.monthly;
}) * 1.5]);

var bars = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d.duration);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.monthly);
  })
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.monthly);
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return colours(d.duration);
  });

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5)
    .tickSizeInner([-width]))
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", "0.71em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("fill", "#5D6971")
  .text("Average House Price - (£)");
```

```css
body {
   background-color: #F1F3F3
 }
 
 .axis {
   font: 15px sans-serif;
 }
 
 .axis path,
 .axis line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #D4D8DA;
   stroke-width: 1px;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.9.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="400"></svg>
```